# How can I optimize query to run faster (Query inside a Query)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This query will take around 5 seconds to complete. I mean when I refresh or navigate to the page it will take 5 seconds to complete the browser loading and to display the total counts.

Here is what I want to achieve, FIRST is to get the MAX value of the systemID (ID) based on the empID.
But before the First query ends I made another query the will get the row where the empID has a JUMP value on the eStatus col.

This is to compare the year difference of the latest data startDate of the empID and to his previous JUMP endDate.

Here is my table

```
---|-------|-----------|------------|---------
ID | empID | startDate |   endDate  | eStatus
---|-------|-----------|------------|---------
1  |   10  | 2001-1-31 | 2001-12-31 |
2  |   10  | 2002-1-31 | 2002-12-31 | 
3  |   22  | 2001-1-31 | 2001-12-31 |
4  |   10  | 2003-1-31 | 2003-12-31 | JUMP
5  |   10  | 2004-1-31 | 2004-12-31 |
6  |   22  | 2002-1-31 | 2002-12-31 | JUMP
7  |   10  | 2005-1-31 | 2005-12-31 |
8  |   22  | 2003-1-31 | 2003-12-31 |
9  |   22  | 2004-1-31 | 2004-12-31 |
10 |   10  | 2006-1-31 | 2006-12-31 | JUMP
11 |   10  | 2007-1-31 | 2007-12-31 |
12 |   10  | 2008-1-31 | 2008-12-31 |
13 |   10  | 2009-1-31 | 2009-12-31 | JUMP
14 |   10  | 2010-1-31 | 2010-12-31 |
15 |   10  | 2011-1-31 | 2011-12-31 |
```

the First query will get the max ID by group of empID.

```
---|-------|-----------|------------|---------
ID | empID | startDate |   endDate  | eStatus
---|-------|-----------|------------|---------
15 |   10  | 2011-1-31 | 2011-12-31 |
9  |   22  | 2004-1-31 | 2004-12-31 |
```

the Second query will get the empID row that has a JUMP data on the eStatus Col

```
---|-------|-----------|------------|---------
ID | empID | startDate |   endDate  | eStatus
---|-------|-----------|------------|---------
4  |   10  | 2003-1-31 | 2003-12-31 | JUMP
6  |   22  | 2002-1-31 | 2002-12-31 | JUMP
10 |   10  | 2006-1-31 | 2006-12-31 | JUMP
13 |   10  | 2009-1-31 | 2009-12-31 | JUMP
6  |   22  | 2002-1-31 | 2002-12-31 | JUMP
```

Now I can compute the date difference from startDate of 1st query and enddate of 2nd query. If it is greater than 2 the it will count to my final count.
THANK YOU SO MUCH IN ADVANCE and KEEP SAFE.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
$counterA= 0;
$counterB= 0;
$finalCount = 0;
                  
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT empID,endDate FROM tablerecord 
  WHERE ID IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tablerecord GROUP BY empID)");
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result )) {
    $counterA++; //count how many result based on the above query
    $emp_max = $row['empID']; //Get emp ID based on max ID
    endDate_result = $row['endDate']; //Get endDate based on max ID
        
    $resultPrevious=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT empID,startDate FROM tablerecord
    WHERE empID = '$emp_max' AND eStatus = 'JUMP' ");
    while ($rowPrevious=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultPrevious)) {
                      
        $counterB++; //count how many result based on the above query
                                            
        $dateA=date_create($rowPrevious['startDate']);
        $dateB=date_create($endDate_result);
                            
        $diff2=date_diff($dateA,$dateB);
        $numLenght = $diff2->y;
                      
                      if ($numLenght > 2) {
                        $finalCount++;
                      }
    }
   }
   echo $counterA;
   echo "<br>";
   echo $counterB;
   echo "<br>";
   echo $finalCount;

?>
```

Comment: why do you need `MAX(ID)`? do you need the unique value or the count? you can use `DISTINCT` to get the unique value

Comment: Hello, I need to get the MAX(ID) so that I can have the latest data of the certain empID. Once I have the latest data then im going to compute the year difference from his previous year where he got his "jump" status.

Comment: Your table schema could use better data types.  Those two date columns should be date type so that you can properly compare values as dates instead of strings.  I am unclear about your desired output.

Comment: hello, the date columns are date types. :) I am trying to get how many empID will going to get "jump" status based on the last endDate data and to its previous jump status startDate :) That query is working but it is too slow. I have only 19000+ records/row,.

Comment: Hello everyone thank you for you response, Im going to try another approach here since the above code takes a lot time to load maybe Im not on the right method to achieve what I want to achieve. Keep safe everyone.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, what you want is to select all data that have `eStatus` value `jump`.

why not simply `SELECT empID,startDate FROM tablerecord WHERE empID IN(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tablerecord) AND eStatus = 'JUMP'`?

or, if you want the unique value of `empID`, `SELECT empID,startDate FROM tablerecord WHERE empID IN(SELECT DISTINCT(ID) FROM tablerecord) AND eStatus = 'JUMP'`

all my query above will not produce any result
you might want to try multiple select in your query for a crude way to get it all in one go

`select * from tablerecord where empID in(SELECT empID FROM tablerecord  WHERE ID IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tablerecord group by empID)) and eStatus = 'JUMP'`

in this way, you only query the DB one time and the rest can be done with your PHP code

Comment: Hello thank you for the response. I want to get the endDate of the latest empID, in order to get that, I need first to get the MAX ID of the certain empID, after that Im going to get the empID endDate where it has a jump estatus. Im sorry If I can't explain it well. :(

Comment: what I dont understand is, how do you determine the `MAX(ID)`. is it by the `endDate`? or simply whatever counted as `MAX` by the DB Engine?

Comment: my bad, it is the `ID`. I'm thought its the `empID`

Answer (score 0):

I would use this query to get all needed data :

```
# Get first and last jump for each empID
SELECT * 
FROM tablerecord t1
WHERE t1.ID = (
    SELECT MIN(t2.ID)
    FROM tablerecord t2
    WHERE t1.empID==t2.empID
) or t1.ID = (
    SELECT MAX(t3.ID)
    FROM tablerecord t3
    WHERE t1.empID==t3.empID
)
```

And then some PHP to run through, comparing each pairs

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"the_previous_query....");
$row_to_compare_with =false;
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result )) {
        if ($row_to_compare_with == false) {
          $row_to_compare_with = $row;
        } else {
           // Compare $row_to_compare_with with $row, both having same empId
           // do your thing here...
           $row_to_compare_with = false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the response :)  My code is working but it takes more than 5 seconds to completely load the data. I sure something is not right. But Ill try another approach.